# useState hook doesn't instantly update the value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a component which has to do some logic onClick.

```
const correctResponse: string = "C";
    const [selectedResponse, setResponse] = useState<string|null>(null);

    const onSubmitAnswer = () => {
        class Coordinate {
            x: number;
            y: number;

            constructor(x: number, y: number) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
        }

        let width: number = box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        let height: number = box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().height;

        let boxCoordinates: Array<Coordinate> = [];
        for(let i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            let data = eval(`box${i+1}`);
            boxCoordinates.push(new Coordinate(data.current.getBoundingClientRect().x, data.current.getBoundingClientRect().y));
        }     
        
        if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[0].x - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().x) < width)
        {
            if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[0].y - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().y) < height)
            {
                setResponse("A");
            }            
        }
        else if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[1].x - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().x) < width)
        {
            if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[1].y - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().y) < height)
            {
                setResponse("B");
            }            
        }
        else if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[2].x - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().x) < width)
        {
            if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[2].y - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().y) < height)
            {               
                setResponse("C");
            }            
        }
        else if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[3].x - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().x) < width)
        {
            if(Math.abs(boxCoordinates[3].y - box0.current.getBoundingClientRect().y) < height)
            {
                setResponse("D");
            }            
        }

        console.log(selectedResponse);       

        if(correctResponse === selectedResponse) {
            console.log("ok");            
        }
        else {
            console.log("raspuns incorect");            
        }
```

Here's the full code, [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFIDKMKMScAvnKVBCHAORSoacDcAKFCRYuOACF8MGBAB22BBADu2AMIQANkxZsO3XjAC0AIwgQYhGFBRhOw8NHgSIAD13suAOgD0L1wKCgqT4chjA8nAacvQxABQAlLiCcKlwaPJW6dA8GMiEkHLEAFxwVlDAcgDmcAC8cABEag1CadlF8ADaxJpIGEgAJvmFxNjEMMOZSAC6dQTENHRIADzllVUAPnL4mpoAfHHbuwlCKWkZHXDyVPgmIMAwAIJFykhQc4l1e8ltbWiaKEIhCi5igA0qSx+v2hrlK2xAJjerWhvwAnnD8AikUEUb8LuV8BhoHFYXB4YioNh0WTMRSkjgzrjoTAABbAQhedz1VzIpm-Vnsryouao3lMxiM34SyVtXrwZTAAasjFY971MyuAAMXjQ+CgPBiXiqSBgLlC4Oqak0wCQMWQGESXgVSpZYtlJrgLKQwCqLJgKopcw12t1+ttMCNJrNcgtVStNrtfRgjq9Pr9p1xcrgGo00AtS0IpUe+pQqOWubBEPo33qnWmbrSpGJWeAtU1-GAywALB2ANS9hIytIMvmpLMDOgoOZIABuKE0cQABhqACQ4YC9gCMjEXJyH0JzoPz9A5YCILMOSGUILzVaQcQntB1eoNEeNpog5vW8fD9uTCU5bBHxQZ8w0Nd9o1jH9EwdADUQSPdcWYNp9zgVDgFIOIAFk6BZLwUBMQg4kPW85ALTpNWmTk4CMbM3BDF9w0jD8v0ta1fyTR1XCSZY4GdVlB1xEdRww7DcPwwjiLcCtjyQQgKKo4VaODUDX2YyDv3YmD-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-Oa6LyUS41Lsm8r6vC73SV+7aHgYD1OQ4DiVDlnBGc9jN5Z-FwLxF7wOV6CgUoNdyBL-qsoCbCqKoCN6Uoc8YZgeFIWocGDZgfBnszliUZQ79HcstDgEABmfvk57cBel7gFebxSicEeJwXeKB96HyQKUTUTAz6V0vhqbccBb6zx8BofYs8MHv0-rPeeOBF5eGXiaVewCJBgLgAMPeB8TBHzgLA0+cBz6ILcPNG+X8mTLHQVoDhuJX7aA-rwlEP93AEP-oAteXA1AUKoRAmhdCGHwIvlfNwSN2FoIwUI6E-CcFaN+CIv+RCAEkKAVwPmMjqFQJgXAphCCVGuC7Oo++3DMHOMfnotoywTBQFQffKQMhIjyHjGgW2l9ri3HuE8F4bxGB7AACoVEiUgAAhFw-xsg5B6K4VPDhe5pRIFcKIeAAxK4oB2PAaIsQYD8CAA)

I observed by logging selectedResponse some strange behaviour.

Let's say I moved box0 over a box, and it matches the first if. The result that is logged is the answer previously stored in selectedResponse. Then if I press the button again, it will log the answer that it should've logged after the last press.

I don't understand why this happens. Example:

```
->app starts
->I move box0 over box1, so it sets the response to A
->console.log prints null (why? the response should've been set to A
```

Can anybody explain to me why does this behavior happen and how can I fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you need to be aware of is that your `setResponse` function that you got from `useState` is *asynchronous*.

This (generally speaking) means that when you call `setResponse` your code will continue executing, regardless of if `setResponse` has actually updated the value yet.

What I would assume is happening in your case is that you call `setResponse("A")` but the `console.log(selectedResponse)` gets executed before `setReponse` has time to finish, hence why `null` is printed (because `null` is the default value you you gave it when you wrote `useState<string|null>(null);`

As another user suggested, an easy way to check if the value of `selectedResponse` has actually updated is to use it inside `useEffect`, like so:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // This code will only be executed when selectedResponse's value changes
}, [selectedResponse])
```